# Implement Blacklist with values in two columns in same row

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to block checkout and display error if firstname and Street address are together found in same row in firstname column and address column respectively in the table "blacklist".
I used the following database query and other codes: I did not use WHERE in the query.

```
    $firstn=  $this->db->query("SELECT firstname FROM  blacklist");
   if ($firstn->num_rows) {
        foreach ($firstn->rows as $result) {
        $blacklistedfirstname[] = $result['firstname'];
    }
}

$addrs=  $this->db->query("SELECT address FROM  blacklist");
  if ($addrs->num_rows) {  
foreach ($addrs->rows as $result) {     
    $blacklistedaddress[] = $result['address'];     
}    
}
$is_f_bl = in_array(ucwords($post['firstname']), $blacklistedfirstname);    
$is_a_bl = in_array(ucwords($post['address']), $blacklistedaddress);
  
if($is_f_bl && $is_a_bl){
      $error = "Oops ! Something went wrong. Contact the administrator";    
}    


The following is the database table name  "blacklist" 

| id   | email  | phone | firstname | address |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|:---- |:------:| 
| 1    | e@e.com    | 999999 | Raj | Street2|
| 2    | b@c.com    | 222222 | Ben | Street1|
| 3    | g@m.com    | 333333 | Ken | Street3|
```

The following sql query is used in PHP:
The issue is When firstname "Raj" which is in the row having ID 1 and address "Street3" which is in row with ID 3 if entered in checkout, blocks with error as blacklisted. It must block only if address Street2 is entered as in ID 1. If Ben and Street1 is entered it must block as blacklisted.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: *I did no use WHERE in the query* any reason?

Comment: @Nigel Ren Because,it throws Undefined variable if I use the below:                                                    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT firstname FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($firstname) . "'");

Comment: But your value is in `$post['firstname']`, also you would be better using prepared statements.

Comment: @Nigel Ren  Yes. $post['firstname'] was defined. But dont know why it throws error.  without WHERE it works. Only thing is the blacklist values taken from any of the rows and blocks checkout. instead each row value together must be the result

Comment: You are trying to use `escape($firstname)` and that isn't the same as the variable which you are saying is defined.  If you sorted that problem out, you could use both fields in the same SQL statement and you wouldn't need all of the loops and values.

Comment: Agreed. If the value you want is in `$post['firstname']`, then it makes no sense that you tried to use `$firstname` in the query. These are different variables (clearly).

Comment: @Nigel Ren $query= $this->db->query("SELECT firstname, address  FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = '" . $this->db->($post['firstname']) . "'")                                                                            Is this correct?

Comment: You've said yourself that the value is in `$post['firstname']` so no it's not correct.

Comment: `$this->db->($post['firstname'])` doesn't appear to make any sense. Why is the `$this->db->` part there?? And that should be giving you a syntax error anyway, so you can see immediately that it's wrong.

Comment: @ ADyson I am using Opencart where checkout.php uses this a standard  way of ccommunication with Database. For general php we will be using mysqli query with local host db name password etc.. and then query.  Shall I use $this->($post['firstname'])   or simply: $query= $this->db->query("SELECT firstname, address FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = '" . ($post['firstname']) . "'")

Comment: `where checkout.php uses this a standard way of ccommunication with Database`...ok but in that situation you're trying to just put a variable into a string. That has nothing to do with communicating with the database. Communicating with the database happens when you've finished building that string, and you send it to be executed, using the `->query()` function.

Comment: `Shall I use $this->($post['firstname'])`...no, because a) again that's a syntax error due to the brackets (don't you have an IDE which shows you stuff like that when you type it??), and b) there's nothing here to indicate that $post is a property of the class you're writing this code inside (although I could of course be wrong, but it would contradict what you yourself said earlier), and c) even if it was, it would need to be `$this->post`. You seem to lack awareness of basic PHP syntax, and you may need to go back and review your core knowledge. Don't try to run before you can walk.

Comment: @ ADyson While pasting I though I removed the brackets. But when I reviwed to edit my comment, Stackoverflow did not allow me to edit.

Comment: If any help to  solve my question above will be good

Comment: It's just basic string concatenation which everyone should know from their very first few PHP lessons: `"SELECT firstname, address FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = '" . $post['firstname']. "'"`. But as mentioned above, this can be insecure or unreliable (imagine if the name was `O'Neill` for example, it would mess up the quote marks!). You need to learn to use prepared statements and parameters for improved reliability.

Comment: @ Adyson I tried the same thing: "SELECT firstname, address FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = '" . $post['firstname']. "'"                                                                                         But did not work. So posted in Opencart forum where, it was told to add $this->db->query etc... So confused

Comment: `did not work`...means what exactly? we need more info than that, to help you. Remember we cannot run your code - you are the one who is responsible for debugging it properly and giving us precise information.  Is there an error? Is the final output unexpected in some way? Did you verify that `$post['firstname']` contains the exact value you expected at runtime, and that there is definitely a matching row in your database? etc. etc. You need to learn to routinely do basic testing like this in your code when things go wrong, otherwise you'll  never be able to fix anything.

Comment: @ADyson The Chekout page goes blank. Server error log has many Errors related to Journal theme 3. May be Journal theme changing core functionality of Opencart. Error ex. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, null given in

Comment: Presumably it gives you a line number and filename so you can go and find that bug, and fix it.

Comment: There are two calls to `in_array` in the code you've shown us above. Does it point to one of those?

Comment: @ADYson Okay. But any solution for blacklist check with firstname and address as in DB column in the same row as posted in my question?

Comment: @ADYson two query statements used and two in_arrays for firstname and address variable respectively. Initially I tested each variable by two queries. But for the solution, if needed, it can be modifed as per your experience.

Comment: `two query statements used and two in_arrays for firstname and address variable respectively`...yes I can see that. My question was - which was of those is failing? The error message you posted should tell you the line number on which the problem occurred.

Comment: `any solution for blacklist check with firstname and address`...well that's what we're trying to work towards, isn't it? But we have a specific error within that, which you need to fix.

Comment: @ ADyson  I have fixed the error and did modified sql query with the correct syntax. Out of some tension I made mistake in pasting the code in my comment. Not that I don't know basic php. I may not be an expert like you, but I can learn new things when experts guide me.

Comment: That's great. So everything is working now? Or is there still a problem? P.s. I'm not a php expert and never claimed to be. Those problems were _basic_ syntax problems, not expert ones. And it wasn't a typo i dont think...you added a whole function call in there which didn't make any sense. But you don't need to defend yourself, I don't care what your level is, as long as people pay attention to to what they're doing. I'm happy you fixed the error :-)

Comment: @ ADyson Whole function I edited in notepad because at that time I could not log into server. I made two edits, copied wrong one when pasting the whole code. I am not actually defending myself, but telling you what exactly happened. Everything works well and no issues after I debugged and found the cause of the Fatal php error.

Comment: I see. You could do with using an IDE locally such as Visual Studio Code, or at the least an editor such as Notepad++ which has some ability to highlight PHP code. They are both free to download. The it's a lot easier than trying to use Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine and optimize it this way:

```php
$fname = ucwords($post['firstname']?? '');    
$addr = ucwords($post['address']?? '');
$stmt=  $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM blacklist WHERE firstname = ? AND address = ?");
$stmt->execute([$fname,$addr]);
if ($stmt->num_rows) {
    $error = "Oops ! Something went wrong. Contact the administrator";  
}
```

Note that searching is DB's task. So leave finding the black listed items to MySQL.

**Never use `query()` function with inputs, it's risky and very unsafe! Learn to use `prepared statements`. [Learn more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**

Comment: Your answer @Alijvhr , is really useful and Worked. Only thing is that I had to change  = question 'mark in db query to a variable with appropriate variables with dot single and double quotes. Also I had to remove $stmt->execute([$fname,$addr]); as it throws error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::execute() in...                          Thank you for your excellent answer

Comment: @VSR No, I used `prepared_statement`s! and you should use the question mark and descriptions in the link! I assumed that `$this->db` is an instance of `mysqli`. please check and use the right way!

Comment: This  @Alijvhr To debug  and test I changed to query instead of prepare and everything worked well. If I use prepare, then I get this error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare() in                                                                                                          
I am still  thinking how to use prepared statement instead of query as you said. I think Opencart not connecting to DB properly when we use prepared statement. is it that ?       I think we have to define DB connection as new conn or something ?

Comment: This @ Alijvhr In this link also it says Opencart not supporting Prepared statements yet. I think something must be added to library section in db.php. Also PDO and Prepared statement will be secure as you said but at present Opencart not accepting it. If you find any solution, please give additional answer to adapt prepared statement into Opencart 3. The link is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744674/how-to-use-parameterized-queries-prepared-statements-in-opencart